# Warning results in failure when reading from AED S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am doing a simple inner join between two tables, but I keep getting the warning shown below. I saw in other posts, that it is ok to ignore the warning, but my jobs end in failure and do not progress. 
The tables are pretty big, (12 billion rows) but I am adding just three columns from one table to the other.
When reduce the dataset to a few million rows and run the script in Amazon Sagemaker Jupyter notebook. it works fine. But when I run it on the EMR cluster for the entire dataset, it fails. I even ran the specific snappy partition that it seemed to fail on, and it worked in sagemaker. 
The job has no problems reading from one of the tables, it is the other table that seems to give the problem

> INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path:
>   s3a://path/EES_FD_UVA_HIST/date=2019-10-14/part-00056-ddb83da5-2e1b-499d-a52a-cad16e21bd2c-c000.snappy.parquet,
>   range: 0-102777097, partition values: [18183] 20/04/06 15:51:58 WARN
>   S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the
>   S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error
>   and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you
>   need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use. 20/04/06
>   15:51:58 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the
>   S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error
>   and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you
>   need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use. 20/04/06
>   15:52:03 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a
>   shutdown 20/04/06 15:52:03 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
>   20/04/06 15:52:03 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped 20/04/06
>   15:52:03 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

This is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
uvalim=spark.read.parquet("s3://path/UVA_HIST_WITH_LIMITS")
uvaorg=spark.read.parquet("s3a://path/EES_FD_UVA_HIST")
config=uvalim.select('SEQ_ID','TOOL_ID', 'DATE' ,'UL','LL')
uva=uvaorg.select('SEQ_ID', 'TOOL_ID', 'TIME_STAMP', 'RUN_ID', 'TARGET', 'LOWER_CRITICAL', 'UPPER_CRITICAL', 'RESULT', 'STATUS')

uva_config=uva.join(config, on=['SEQ_ID','TOOL_ID'], how='inner')

uva_config.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3a://path/Uvaconfig.parquet")
```

Is there a way to debug this?

**Update: Based on Emerson's suggestion:**

I ran it with the debug log. It ran for 9 hours with a Fail before i killed the yarn application. 
For some reason the stderr did not have much output

[image: Job Stage]
[image: Job Executions]

This is the stderr output:

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found
>   binding in
>   [jar:file:/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/301/__spark_libs__1712836156286367723.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 20/04/07 05:04:13 INFO
>   CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name:
>   5653@ip-10-210-13-51 20/04/07 05:04:13 INFO SignalUtils: Registered
>   signal handler for TERM 20/04/07 05:04:13 INFO SignalUtils: Registered
>   signal handler for HUP 20/04/07 05:04:13 INFO SignalUtils: Registered
>   signal handler for INT 20/04/07 05:04:15 INFO SecurityManager:
>   Changing view acls to: yarn,hadoop 20/04/07 05:04:15 INFO
>   SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,hadoop 20/04/07
>   05:04:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:  20/04/07
>   05:04:15 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
>   20/04/07 05:04:15 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager:
>   authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view
>   permissions: Set(yarn, hadoop); groups with view permissions: Set();
>   users  with modify permissions: Set(yarn, hadoop); groups with modify
>   permissions: Set() 20/04/07 05:04:15 INFO TransportClientFactory:
>   Successfully created connection to
>   ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal/10.210.13.51:35863 after 168 ms (0 ms
>   spent in bootstraps) 20/04/07 05:04:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing
>   view acls to: yarn,hadoop 20/04/07 05:04:16 INFO SecurityManager:
>   Changing modify acls to: yarn,hadoop 20/04/07 05:04:16 INFO
>   SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:  20/04/07 05:04:16 INFO
>   SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:  20/04/07 05:04:16
>   INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui
>   acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(yarn, hadoop); groups
>   with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions:
>   Set(yarn, hadoop); groups with modify permissions: Set() 20/04/07
>   05:04:16 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection
>   to ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal/10.210.13.51:35863 after 20 ms (0 ms
>   spent in bootstraps) 20/04/07 05:04:16 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created
>   local directory at
>   /mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1569338404918_1241/blockmgr-2adfe133-fd28-4f25-95a4-2ac1348c625e
>   20/04/07 05:04:16 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at
>   /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1569338404918_1241/blockmgr-3620ceea-8eee-42c5-af2f-6975c894b643
>   20/04/07 05:04:17 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity
>   3.8 GB 20/04/07 05:04:17 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver:
>   spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal:35863
>   20/04/07 05:04:17 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully
>   registered with driver 20/04/07 05:04:17 INFO Executor: Starting
>   executor ID 1 on host ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal 20/04/07 05:04:18
>   INFO Utils: Successfully started service
>   'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port
>   34073. 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal:34073 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO
>   BlockManager: Using
>   org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block
>   replication policy 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster:
>   Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(1,
>   ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal, 34073, None) 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO
>   BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(1,
>   ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal, 34073, None) 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO
>   BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337 20/04/07 05:04:18
>   INFO BlockManager: Registering executor with local external shuffle
>   service. 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully
>   created connection to ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal/10.210.13.51:7337
>   after 19 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps) 20/04/07 05:04:18 INFO
>   BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(1,
>   ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal, 34073, None) 20/04/07 05:04:20 INFO
>   CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 0 20/04/07 05:04:20
>   INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) 20/04/07 05:04:21
>   INFO TorrentBroadcast: Started reading broadcast variable 0 20/04/07
>   05:04:21 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection
>   to ip-10-210-13-51.ec2.internal/10.210.13.51:38181 after 17 ms (0 ms
>   spent in bootstraps) 20/04/07 05:04:21 INFO MemoryStore: Block
>   broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 39.4 KB,
>   free 3.8 GB) 20/04/07 05:04:21 INFO TorrentBroadcast: Reading
>   broadcast variable 0 took 504 ms 20/04/07 05:04:22 INFO MemoryStore:
>   Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 130.2 KB,
>   free 3.8 GB) 20/04/07 05:04:23 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:
>   eagerFSInit: Eagerly initialized FileSystem at s3://does/not/exist in
>   5155 ms 20/04/07 05:04:25 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage
>   0.0 (TID 0). 53157 bytes result sent to driver 20/04/07 05:04:25 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 2 20/04/07 05:04:25
>   INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) 20/04/07 05:04:25
>   INFO Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2). 53114 bytes
>   result sent to driver 20/04/07 05:04:25 INFO
>   CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 3 20/04/07 05:04:25
>   INFO Executor: Running task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) 20/04/07 05:04:25
>   ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM 20/04/07
>   05:04:25 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called 20/04/07 05:04:25
>   INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after troubleshooting the Debugs, I came to the conclusion that it was indeed a memory issue. 
The cluster I was using was running out of memory after loading a few days worth of data. Each day was about 2 billion rows. 
So I tried parsing my script by each day which it seemed to be able to handle.
However when handling some days where the data was a slightly larger (7 billion rows), it gave me a

> executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

error. This [post](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21733) by Jumpman solved the problem by simply extending the `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout` value

So thank you @Emerson and @Jumpman!

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch to using s3 instead of s3a. i belive s3a is not recommended for use in EMR. Additionaly, You can run your job in debug.

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel('DEBUG')
```

Read the below document that talks about s3a
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html

Comment: I did try running it with s3 instead of s3a but got the same issue. I will try the DEBUG method and see what I get. Where would I be able to access the debug logs?

Comment: if you are doing a spark submit, it will be available on your console based on the default log4j settings